# How can i check if movie id is equal to key from Map

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to play movie based on movie ID from TMDB API.

```
Map<int, String> listaFilmova = {
    111111: 'https://aaaaaaaaa',
    222222: 'https://bbbbbbbbb',
  };
```

Here is what I use to play video and where I want to get the value from map based on movie ID and key from the Map

```
widget.browser.openUrlRequest(
                                urlRequest: URLRequest(
                                  url: Uri.parse(
                                    'https://aaaaaaaaa',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                options: options,
                              );
```

I tried searching for a long time, but I am just not experienced enough to figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please use listaFilmova.contains(your_key_value) to check whether the key is present in the map.
If the above code returns true, then use listaFilmova[your_key_value] to retrieve the value assigned against the key.
In this case the url.

Comment: Hi, i tried but when i use listaFilmova[mine_key_value] it bring the error ''The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.''

Comment: In case the value is non-null: listaFilmova[mine_key_value!]

Comment: The value which you are trying to assign is of the type String?. Your map has the type String,String. You can't assign String to String?. Make sure the value is not null using a null check before assignment.